# Included file unaccessible in if/else statement?

Tags: php, include

So this is my code: http://pastebin.com/3jELA420 I'm trying to store my password using phpass and for some reason the included file is not being accessed in my else statement. I get the error:
Fatal error: Class 'PasswordHash' not found in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/forms/registersecure.php on line 33

This is related to a thread I posted not too long ago ([Registration page: Storing password using PHPASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259320/registration-page-storing-password-using-phpass#)), but I feel like this is more succinct thread as I feel I have isolated the problem.

Comment: are you absolutely sure that there is a file "/home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/includes/PasswordHash.php" ? and it contains the PasswordHash class ?

Comment: Try using "require_once" instead of "include" for your file.

Comment: using require_once changes the error to this:

string(0) ""
Warning: require_once(/home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/includes/PasswordHash.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/forms/registersecure.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/includes/PasswordHash.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/forms/registersecure.php on line 4

Comment: You don't have read access on that file. You will need to `chmod` the file so that the user your apache runs under can read the file. The user that your apache runs under is usually something like `www-data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your respond, PHP doesn't have enough permissions to access the file : 
Please read more about it [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php)

Also please [check this responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941282/php-permission-denied-despite-appropriate-permissions)

Please try:

```
chmod /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/includes/PasswordHash.php  755
```

Comment: If I had the rep to upvote you I would; this solved my issue.